# Textboxes in Asp.Net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, textcolor

How to **get different colors of text** in a **text box** in ASP.NET when words printed in the Text Box are dynamic using database? Please help! There is rich text box for this purpose in Window Form but what about the web forms?

Comment: Do you mean different color for every letter inside of textbox?

Comment: You can use regex and check if text contains this word, then assign particular color.

Comment: @ItiTyagi and how would you display that in a textbox?

Comment: We don't need to display that regex in texbox, its just we match the text coming into textbox with a regex. And assign colors according to that.

Comment: @ItiTyagi OP needs to display colors in a text box

Comment: Please have a look at your question title!! Does it look like a problem?

Comment: @Yuriy: No he needs to show the text color, not the text box color.

Comment: @ItiTyagi yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Standard ASP.NET TextBox renders as `<input type="text">` which does not support styles for individual characters.

You can use a 3rd party tool or, at a very basic you can use DIV with contenteditable set to true:

Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pr9mm/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a rich-text box to use - try the HTMLEditor in the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorials&referringTitle=Documentation). It is essentially the same functionality. Just make sure to put a sanitizer on it to avoid XSS problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check the accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254582/change-forecolor-af-a-special-word-in-gridview-cell) question. Eventhough it is for gridview the same logic could be used for textbox also. Hope this helps you in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [HtmlEditorExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx) from the ajax control toolkit. You can also configure how the textbox looks.