# change forecolor af a special word in gridview cell

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, colors

I want to change the color of some **special words** NOT all words in a gridview cell.
 Here is the code:

```
protected void gvContents_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text.Contains("Special"))
        {
            //set The "Special" word only forecolor to red
        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "Perishable")
        {
            //set The "Perishable" word only forecolor to blue
        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "Danger")
        {
            //set The "Danger" word only forecolor to yellow
        }
    }
}
```

and the cell text might be like here: `Radioactive : Danger` or this: `Human Body : Special ,Perishable`. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of [span tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) and CSS classes. First create the CSS classes in your aspx code:

```
<style>
    .redWord
    {
        color: Red;
    }
    .blueWord
    {
        color: Blue;
    }
    .yellowWord
    {
        color: Yellow;
    }
</style>
```

then replace all occurences of `Special` to `<span class='redWord'>Special</span>`, `Perishable` to `<span class='blueWord'>Perishable</span>`, and `Danger` to `<span class='yellowWord'>Danger</span>`:

```
protected void gvContents_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = e.Row.Cells[3].Text.Replace("Special", "<span class='redWord'>Special</span>")
                              .Replace("Perishable", "<span class='blueWord'>Perishable</span>")
                              .Replace("Danger", "<span class='yellowWord'>Danger</span>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CellFormatting event handler, add the below code

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() == "Special")
        {
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Juniaith , but this code change the color of entire cell , I want change the color of that word only!!

Comment: If you want to change the color of a specific word you have to use customized column similar to RichEditTextColumn given [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView)